# When importing a Google form submission to a spreadsheet, how do I automatically change the time format from "d-m-yyy" to "dd-mmm-yyy"

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-workspace-for-business

I am importing information from a Google form into a spreadsheet. It imports live. It creates a time stamp. There are also several other dates in the form (when you type it into the form there is only one accepted date format). How can I make it so that every time the form is updated the form is also updated?

Comment: "How can I make it so that every time the form is updated the form is also updated" I *think* you mean "How can I make it so that every time the form is updated the date is also updated"?

Comment: What spreadsheet software are you using?